Google BigQuery permission error while using Go APIs
After authenticating to Google BigQuery using Google account, while using BigQuery console, I'm able to run my queries. These queries create a job (visible in pop ups).
But while executing the same with Go program running remotely, I get an error that I do not have create.job permission. I'm using the same Google account for authentication.
Does anybody know what can be the issue? Is any other account (like service account) used for running queries with APIs?


Incorrect IAM Permissions
Ensure the service account or user making the request has the required permissions for the operation. For example:

For querying data, you need bigquery.dataViewer or bigquery.user.
For creating datasets, you need bigquery.dataOwner.
Solution:
Assign the correct IAM roles to the service account via the Google Cloud Console.
Go to IAM & Admin > IAM.
Add or modify the roles assigned to your service account or user.

It's the same principal making the queries - once via BQ console and then via Go API. Why should the permissions change?
